# Add values of subarray with different numbers of sub-elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of this structure:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => Array
>                 (
>                     [year] => 2014
>                     [weeknumber] => 1
>                     [foo1] => 1
>                     [foo2] => 2
>                     [foo3] => 3
>                 )
>             [1] => Array
>                 (
>                     [year] => 2014
>                     [weeknumber] => 2
>                     [foo1] => 1
>                     [foo2] => 2
>                     [foo3] => 3
>                 )
>             [2] => Array
>                 (
>                     [year] => 2014
>                     [weeknumber] => 3
>                     [foo1] => 1
>                     [foo2] => 2
>                     [foo3] => 3
>                 )
>         )
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => Array
>                 (
>                     [year] => 2014
>                     [weeknumber] => 1
>                     [foo1] => 1
>                     [foo2] => 2
>                     [foo3] => 3
>                 )
>             [1] => Array
>                 (
>                     [year] => 2014
>                     [weeknumber] => 2
>                     [foo1] => 1
>                     [foo2] => 2
>                     [foo3] => 3
>                 )
>             [2] => Array
>                 (
>                     [year] => 2014
>                     [weeknumber] => 3
>                     [foo1] => 1
>                     [foo2] => 2
>                     [foo3] => 3
>                 )
>         )
> )
> ```

I count the sub-elements with this function:

> ```
> $final = array();
> foreach($array as $index1 => $sub_array1)
> {
> $i = 0;
>     foreach($sub_array1 as $index2 => $final_sub_array)
>     {
>         $wn = $final_sub_array['weeknumber'];
>         $year = $final_sub_array['year'];
>         unset($final_sub_array['year']);
>         unset($final_sub_array['weeknumber']);
>         foreach($final_sub_array as $key => $value)
>         {
>             if(isset($final[$i][$key])) {
>                 $final[$i][$key] += $value;
>             }
>             else {
>                 $final[$i][$key] = $value;
>             }
>             $final[$i]['kw'] = $wn;
>             $final[$i]['jahr'] = $year;
>         }
>     $i++;
>     }
> }
> ```

The script only works if $ final_sub_array always has the same number of elements. 
But if one arrray has only 1 or 2 elements and the others have more, it no longer works. How can I fix that?
All entries with the same year and the same week number must be added together.

---

Here is the code to play with:

```
<?php
$var =
array (
113 => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1537',
    'kw' => '22',
    'jahr' => '2014',
    'anzahl_betten' => '10',
    'zugange_dauerpflege' => '0',
    'zugange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_sterbefalle' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_auszuge' => '0',
    'abgange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'wechsel_kurz_dauer' => '0',
    'anzahl_tage' => '0',
    'geplante_einzuge' => '0',
    'hID' => '113',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1541',
    'kw' => '23',
    'jahr' => '2014',
    'anzahl_betten' => '10',
    'zugange_dauerpflege' => '0',
    'zugange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_sterbefalle' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_auszuge' => '0',
    'abgange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'wechsel_kurz_dauer' => '0',
    'anzahl_tage' => '0',
    'geplante_einzuge' => '0',
    'hID' => '113',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1543',
    'kw' => '24',
    'jahr' => '2014',
    'anzahl_betten' => '10',
    'zugange_dauerpflege' => '0',
    'zugange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_sterbefalle' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_auszuge' => '0',
    'abgange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'wechsel_kurz_dauer' => '0',
    'anzahl_tage' => '0',
    'geplante_einzuge' => '0',
    'hID' => '113',
  ),
),
114 => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1538',
    'kw' => '22',
    'jahr' => '2014',
    'anzahl_betten' => '10',
    'zugange_dauerpflege' => '0',
    'zugange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_sterbefalle' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_auszuge' => '0',
    'abgange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'wechsel_kurz_dauer' => '0',
    'anzahl_tage' => '0',
    'geplante_einzuge' => '0',
    'hID' => '114',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1540',
    'kw' => '23',
    'jahr' => '2014',
    'anzahl_betten' => '10',
    'zugange_dauerpflege' => '0',
    'zugange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_sterbefalle' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_auszuge' => '0',
    'abgange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'wechsel_kurz_dauer' => '0',
    'anzahl_tage' => '0',
    'geplante_einzuge' => '0',
    'hID' => '114',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1544',
    'kw' => '24',
    'jahr' => '2014',
    'anzahl_betten' => '10',
    'zugange_dauerpflege' => '0',
    'zugange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_sterbefalle' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_auszuge' => '0',
    'abgange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'wechsel_kurz_dauer' => '0',
    'anzahl_tage' => '0',
    'geplante_einzuge' => '0',
    'hID' => '114',
  ),
),
115 => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1539',
    'kw' => '22',
    'jahr' => '2014',
    'anzahl_betten' => '10',
    'zugange_dauerpflege' => '0',
    'zugange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_sterbefalle' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_auszuge' => '0',
    'abgange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'wechsel_kurz_dauer' => '0',
    'anzahl_tage' => '0',
    'geplante_einzuge' => '0',
    'hID' => '115',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1542',
    'kw' => '23',
    'jahr' => '2014',
    'anzahl_betten' => '10',
    'zugange_dauerpflege' => '0',
    'zugange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_sterbefalle' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_auszuge' => '0',
    'abgange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'wechsel_kurz_dauer' => '0',
    'anzahl_tage' => '0',
    'geplante_einzuge' => '0',
    'hID' => '115',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1545',
    'kw' => '24',
    'jahr' => '2014',
    'anzahl_betten' => '10',
    'zugange_dauerpflege' => '0',
    'zugange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_sterbefalle' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_auszuge' => '0',
    'abgange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'wechsel_kurz_dauer' => '0',
    'anzahl_tage' => '0',
    'geplante_einzuge' => '0',
    'hID' => '115',
  ),
),
116 => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1546',
    'kw' => '24',
    'jahr' => '2014',
    'anzahl_betten' => '10',
    'zugange_dauerpflege' => '0',
    'zugange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_sterbefalle' => '0',
    'abgange_dauerpflege_auszuge' => '0',
    'abgange_kurzzeitpflege' => '0',
    'wechsel_kurz_dauer' => '0',
    'anzahl_tage' => '0',
    'geplante_einzuge' => '0',
    'hID' => '116',
  ),
),
);
foreach($var as $index1 => $sub_array1)
{
$i = 0;
  foreach($sub_array1 as $index2 => $final_sub_array)
  {
      $kw = $final_sub_array['kw'];
      $jahr = $final_sub_array['jahr'];
      unset($final_sub_array['id']);
      unset($final_sub_array['kw']);
      unset($final_sub_array['jahr']);
      unset($final_sub_array['hID']);
      foreach($final_sub_array as $key => $value)
      {
          if(isset($final[$i][$key])) {
              $final[$i][$key] += $value;
          }
          else {
              $final[$i][$key] = $value;
          }
          $final[$i]['kw'] = $kw;
          $final[$i]['jahr'] = $jahr;
      }
    $i++;
  }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

if you delete the last array with the key 116 everything is working. But with it, it doubles the kw 24 and counts wrong.

Comment: I don't see where the code requires all the subarrays to have the same number of elements. And don't you think you should have shown input data where the number of elements is different?

Comment: The question is based on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044633/calculate-data-from-an-array

Comment: That doesn't clarify the problem. Could you show the input data that causes the problem, and the result you're trying to get from it?

Comment: With input data you mean the content of $array?

Comment: It would be best if you showed it in a format we can copy and paste into a PHP script to test with. Use `var_export` for this, not `var_dump` or `print_r`.

Comment: I simplified the input data. It contains 4 houses. 3 have entries for 3 weeks and one has just one entry for one week.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fjy1jaazba46vu/array.txt
week number ist "kw" and year is "jahr"

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you want. It uses `$kw` as the key of the final array, not `$i`, so that it combines sub-arrays with the same `kw` value. I'm a little confused about what you're doing with `jahr`, though. If there are entries with the same `kw` but different `jahr`, the final result will have the last `jahr`.

```
foreach($var as $index1 => $sub_array1)
{
  foreach($sub_array1 as $index2 => $final_sub_array)
  {
      $kw = $final_sub_array['kw'];
      $jahr = $final_sub_array['jahr'];
      unset($final_sub_array['id']);
      unset($final_sub_array['kw']);
      unset($final_sub_array['jahr']);
      unset($final_sub_array['hID']);
      foreach($final_sub_array as $key => $value)
      {
          if(isset($final[$kw][$key])) {
              $final[$kw][$key] += $value;
          }
          else {
              $final[$kw][$key] = $value;
          }
          $final[$kw]['kw'] = $kw;
          $final[$kw]['jahr'] = $jahr;
      }
    $i++;
  }
}
```

BTW, if this is coming from a database query, it seems like you would be able to get the database to do all the summing for you, with `SUM(col1+col2+col3...) ... GROUP BY kw`.